# What is the "Reserved" Barcode type for Postal Barcodes in ZPL

Tags: printing, barcode, label, zpl

The command for printing a postal barcode in ZPL is :

```
^BZo,h,f,g,t
```

The parameter t can have the following options :

```
0 = Postnet bar code
1 = Plant Bar Code
2 = Reserved
3 = USPS Intelligent Mail bar code
```

I am aware what 0,1,3 are, but I can not seem to find out what option 2, or the Reserved option, represents. Anyone know what this option might be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means "reserved for future use".  It is not explicit, but if you search through the [ZPL manual](https://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra/manuals/en-us/software/zpl-zbi2-pm-en.pdf) looking for "reserved" they use it in a lot of commands that are tied to standards bodies as they expect changes in standards over time.  ^CI, ^HW, ^MM, ^RF, ^RS all have reserved parameters.  Even some of the character sets list "reserved" slots.

The Zebra engineers are just being proactive to be able to accommodate changes to standards.

Comment: Did you have anything to defend that answer?